# Need help with a query

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi have a 2 tables organized in this way:

```
table_users
|user_id|username|

table_products
|product_id|user_id|
```

Now, I have some orphan entries in 'table_products'. 
With this query I check how many products I have:

```
SELECT count(product_id) FROM table_products
```

This query show me the number of the products associated to the users:

```
SELECT p.product_id, u.username
FROM table_products AS p
JOIN table_users AS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
```

I need a query that allow me to select and remove all the orphans products.
Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2):

### Using NOT IN:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS 
 WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT u.user_id
                         FROM TABLE_USERS u)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                     FROM TABLE_USERS u
                    WHERE u.user_id = TABLE_PRODUCTS.user_id)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   DELETE TABLE_PRODUCTS 
     FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS p
LEFT JOIN TABLE_USERS u ON u.user_id = p.user_id
    WHERE u.user_id IS NULL
```

### Efficiency (MySQL only)

If the `TABLE_PRODUCTS.user_id` [is nullable, the NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are more efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/) choices.  Otherwise, the [LEFT JOIN is the most efficient choice in MySQL when the columns compared can not be null](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).

### Addendum

Check and double check that you are selecting the correct rows for deletion before performing the action by swapping out "DELETE FROM" for "SELECT * FROM".  Additionally, if using InnoDB tables - encapsulate the DELETE in a transaction so you can use `ROLLBACK` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I am not taking any responsibility for data deleted with this query. Always test on test database before running on production data.

```
DELETE p 
FROM table_products AS p 
LEFT JOIN table_users AS u 
USING (user_id) 
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL
```